# usernametoken-auth rampart/axis2 1.6.2

Tags: java, web-services, security, apache-axis

I just upgraded to the latest axis2/rampart version and encounter a strange behavior when providing a webservice which requires username-passwort authentification.

up to now, I implemented my own passwordcallback-handler which handled WSPasswordCallbacks of type WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN_UNKNOWN. I looked up the provided user in the DB and checked the given password.

in the latest version, the passwordcallback-usage always seems to be WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN where I have to provide the password for the given user - but I'm not able to provide the password, because I don't store the passwords plaintext.
do I have to write my own org.apache.ws.security.validate.UsernameTokenValidator? where do I have to register it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a summary here on Stackoverflow of my encounter with this problem, and the workarounds I've found to this, [read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817145/axis2-user-authentication/14998964#14998964).